# How do you obtain the $(2,3,7)$ triangle group as a quotient of the modular group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation, modular-group

So, at various places on Wikipedia (like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(2,3,7)_triangle_group)), its claimed that the $(2,3,7)$ triangle group can be obtained as quotient of the modular group. How is this done?

Treating the integers as mod $7$ will obviously create a finite group (which is apparently isomorphic to the $(2,3,7)$ triangle group, but on the Klein Quartic instead of the entire hyperbolic plane). [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Quotients) is saying that, treating the elements of the modular group as fractional linear transformations, you can just wrap the space it is acting on mod $7$ in the $x$ axis. It appears that you still have tons of triangles with infinite order vertices though this way.

It seems like you could get the group by modding by the normal closure of $\{T^7\}$, where $T^7$ is the act of rotating about an ideal vertice $7$ times. This may just lead to the Klein Quartic though again, I'm not sure.

Is there some way that $(2,3,7)$ can be obtained as a quotient of the modular group?

Comment: Is the tesellation from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-7_triangular_tiling, picture https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Order-7_triangular_tiling.svg the wanted answer?!

Comment: @dan_fulea the group is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%282%2C3%2C7%29_triangle_group). It generates that tiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modular group can be generated by the transformations $s\colon z\mapsto -1/z$ and $r\colon z\mapsto -1/z-1$, which obey the relations $s^2=r^3=1$. To get the $(2,3,7)$ triangle group, we need the additional relation $(sr)^7=1$, so we need to take quotient by $z\mapsto z/(1+7z)$.

Comment: So since the modular group (as matrices) is isomorphic to the finitely presented group, the result of taking the quotient will also be isomorphic, right? I think I get it. The only thing I wonder is what the kernel of the quotient map is, but that wasn't part of my original question. Thank you!

Comment: Here's my follow up question: <https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3613411/49592>. It is asking more concretely about determining if the matrices are equivalent in the quotient.