# How do determine if two matrices in the modular group are equivalent as elements of (2,3,7)

Tags: representation-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation, infinite-groups, modular-group

Following up from [How do you obtain the $(2,3,7)$ triangle group as a quotient of the modular group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609516/how-do-you-obtain-the-2-3-7-triangle-group-as-a-quotient-of-the-modular-grou), I'm trying to understand the (2,3,7) triangle group as a quotient as the modular group.

So, we are taking the modular group mod $\{(sr)^7\}$, where $(sr)^7$ is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 7 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ My question is given two 2 by 2 matrices, how do you determine if they are equivalent in this quotient group?

---

I determined that the conjugates of $(sr)^7$ are

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 + 7bd & -7b^2 \\ 7d^2 & 1 - 7bd \end{bmatrix}$$

for any coprime $b$ and $d$. This is just the result of conjugating by $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$. There existing a matrix with determinant $1$ and a given $b$ and $d$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $b$ and $d$ being coprime, by Bézout's identity. The group generated by those conjugates is the normal closure of $\{(sr)^7\}$, so modding the modular group by it gives us the (2,3,7)-triangle group. The issue is that I do not know a good way to describe this subgroup. It is a subgroup of [$\Gamma(7)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup#Principal_congruence_subgroups), but that is about as far as I got. (It is also infinite index in the modular group since the triangle group is infinite.)